# LINQ many-to-many intersection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to query `Posts` based on a list of `Tags`:

```
public class Post
{
  public int? Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}
public class Tag
{
  public int? Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public vritual ICollection<Post> Posts {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to return posts based a list of tags:
`IList<Tag> searchTags = ParseTagsFromSearchString("tag1,tag2,tag3"); // this function checks the tags in the database, so all the primary keys are available in the list`

When a post contains one or more tags that also exists in `searchTags` it should be included in the result. I have tried the following:

```
var q = from s in Context.Registrations
                    where s.Tags.Intersect(tagList)
                    select s;
```

Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Tag>' to 'bool'`

```
var q = from s in Context.Registrations
                    where s.Tags.Any(t => tagList.Any(t2 => t.Id.Value == t2.Id.Value))
                    select s;
```

Runtime error: `NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.Tag'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`
Any ideas?

-- update Jan. 4:
The answers point to the right solution, but in my code I still have the NotSupportedException. Is it possible the nullable integer causes this since it is not a primitive type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I encountered this problem again, and decided to solve it. The problem of my question is that the `IList<Tag> searchTags = ParseTagsFromSearchString("tag1,tag2,tag3");` produces a list, which will cause an exception when used in an intersect expression of another query in entity framework. The right thing to do is this:

```
var q = ParseTagsFromSearchString("tag1,tag2,tag3"); // this function will now build a query instead of a list
IList<Post> posts = (from s in Context.Posts where s.Tags.Intersect(q.AsEnumerable()).Any() select s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, just change the `Intersect(taglist)` to `Intersect(taglist).Any()`

Here's a working example (going along your definitions for `Post` and `Tag`):

```
Tag tag1 = new Tag() { Id = 1, Name = "tag1" };
Tag tag2 = new Tag() { Id = 2, Name = "tag2" };
Tag tag3 = new Tag() { Id = 3, Name = "tag3" };

List<Post> posts = new List<Post>() {
    new Post() { Id = 1, Name = "post1", Tags = new Tag[] {tag1} },
    new Post() { Id = 2, Name = "post2", Tags = new Tag[] {tag2} },
    new Post() { Id = 3, Name = "post3", Tags = new Tag[] {tag3} },
    new Post() { Id = 4, Name = "post13", Tags = new Tag[] {tag1, tag3} },
};

List<Tag> searchTags = new List<Tag>() { tag1, tag2 };

IEnumerable<Post> matching = posts.Where(p => p.Tags.Intersect(searchTags).Any());
//matching now contains post1, post2 and post13
```

now, in real code you probably won't use the same instances for tags in the search list and the Posts, so you'll have to override Equals and GetHashCode for Tag or provide an IEqualityComparer in the call to Intersect

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I got this error: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.Tag'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`

Comment: I've added a working code sample. Hope it helps. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the nested Any() call in your update.

Comment: I implemented an IEqualityComparer, but got this error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...`. As I said in my question, I think the primitive types error is caused by `int?`. Unfortunately I can't test it in my app because some of the code is already in production.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your TagList to a list of integer Ids. Use that in your query to fix the NotSupportedException.

```
var tagIds = tagList.Select(x=>x.Id);
```

Then use tagIds in your query...

```
var q = from s in Context.Registrations
                    where s.Tags.Any(t => tagIds.Any(t2 => t.Id.Value == t2.Id))
                    select s;
```

I'm not sure if nesting Any statements like that will actually work. Just explaining why you were getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work?

```
var q = from s in Context.Registrations
                    where s.Tags.Intersect(tagList).Count() != 0
                    select s;
```

or maybe

```
var q = from s in Context.Registrations
                    where s.Tags.Any(t => tagList.Contains(t))
                    select s;
```

Haven't tried any of this though, so no guarantees :)

Comment: I have tried the second solution in the LinqPad code of Mark Lindel's post and it works. Unfortunately, in my code I got the same UnsupportedException..

Answer (score 0):

Threw this together in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/):

```
void Main()
{
   var tag1 = new Tag { Name = "tag1" };
   var tag2 = new Tag { Name = "tag2" };
   var tag3 = new Tag { Name = "tag3" };

    var posts = new List<Post>
    {   
        new Post 
        {
            Name = "Post1",
            Tags = new List<Tag> { tag1, tag3 }
        },
        new Post 
        {
            Name = "Post2",
            Tags = new List<Tag> { tag2, tag3 }
        }
    };

    var tagList = new List<Tag> { tag1 };

    var q = posts.Where(x => x.Tags.Intersect(tagList).Any());

    q.Dump();
}

public class Post 
{ 
  public int? Id {get;set;} 
  public string Name {get;set;} 
  public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get;set;} 
} 

public class Tag 
{ 
  public int? Id {get;set;} 
  public string Name {get;set;} 
  public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts {get;set;} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in LinqPad this works indeed (nice tool btw), but in my code I get `Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.Tag'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.` Very strange since this code and my code is more or less the same.